# Is it possible to set php.ini to use multiple error logs?

Tags: php

My current php.ini reads:
error_log = error_log

And it is fine, it logs the errors of all scripts into separate files, depending on what folder they are in. So it gives a result like this:

```
public_html/error_log
public_html/folder1/error_log
public_html/folder2/error_log
```

But is it also possible to, in addition to this, make it log to one general error_log? Like below?

```
public_html/general_error_log_for_all_folders
public_html/error_log
public_html/folder1/error_log
public_html/folder2/error_log
```

Comment: You can create a script that scans all directories for error logs. Check [RecursiveIterator](http://php.net/RecursiveIterator)

Comment: If you provide an absolute path in your `php.ini` PHP will log all errors into one file. So yuo will get the one with all the errors but loose the separate logs. If you want to keep both @Mihai's solution seems to be the best.

Answer (score 2):

```
error_log = /absolute/path/to/error_log
```

if you want to setup different error logs for some applications, use runtime config, .htaccess for example

```
php_value error_log = /absolute/path/to/public_html/certain/app/error_log
```